# Como puedo borrar el fichero que he subido para los test de subidas de ficheros si no se el uniqid del nombre

Tags: php, laravel, test, tdd

estoy haciendo un test, en el que estoy subiendo un fake file (sin problemas) pero claro, ahora quiero **comprobar que esta subido** y una vez eso **borrarlo ya que es un test**.
Pero claro no puedo borrarlo porque desde aqui no se el nombre del fichero, solo estoy llamando a la ruta y pasandole cosas, como haria un usuario, y eso un no sabe (ni deberia) saberlo, como puedo hacer para :

1. Obtener el nombre con el que lo he almacenado.

> Uniqid '_' nombre real del fichero . extension

2. Borrar el fichero.

---

Aqui dejo el codigo:

```
   <?php
        
        namespace Tests\Feature;
        
        use App\Models\CustomFile;
        use App\Models\Model3D;
        use App\Models\User;
        use Faker\Factory;
        use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
        use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
        use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
        use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
        use Tests\TestCase;
        
        class Model3DCrudTest extends TestCase
        {
            use DatabaseTransactions;
        
            /**
             * A basic feature test example.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function testStore()
            {
                $this->withoutMiddleware();
        
                $user = User::factory()->create();
                $file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('test-model-3d.obj', 100);
        
                Auth::login($user);
        
                $data = [
                    'title'=>'title test',
                    'description'=>'description test',
                    'file'=>$file
                ];
        
                $response = $this->post('/model',$data);
        
                $response->assertStatus(200);
        
                //Check if file exist
        
                $pathFile = '';
                CustomFile::exists($pathFile);
        
                //Remove test file
        
            }
        }
```

---

Para usar el storage me he creado una clase custom de ficheros:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class CustomFile
{

    public const  MODELS_ROOT_DIR = 'models3D';


    public static function defaultDisk()
    {
        return Storage::disk('public');
    }


    public static function store($file,$test = false){
        $uniqueFileName = uniqid().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $stored =  self::defaultDisk()->put(self::MODELS_ROOT_DIR."\\".$uniqueFileName,  File::get($file));
        $result = [
            'stored' => $stored,
            'unique_file_name'=>$uniqueFileName
        ];
        return $result;
    }

    public static function remove(string  $filename)
    {
        $removed = self::defaultDisk()->delete(self::MODELS_ROOT_DIR."\\".$filename);

        return $removed;
    }

    public static function exists(string $path)
    {
        $exists = self::defaultDisk()->exists($path);
        return $exists;
    }
}
```

Pero claro ese no accedo directamente sino al controlador. Entonces no se como podria terminar esos dos pasos.

Answer (score 0):

que tal

Tienes 3 alternativas:

1. Devolver el nombre del archivo final en la Response del post. Así lo buscas y lo eliminas directamente.
2. Otra opción es pasar este id desde el cliente. Así sabes de ante mano que id tiene y puedes eliminarlo. Esto no es un hack, se usa mucho en DDD Y CQRS.
3. Escanear el directorio y buscar los archivos que coincidan con la parte final del nombre, en este caso "test-model-3d.obj", y eliminarlos. El problema con esta solución es que si de pronto tienes muchos archivos o el filesystem es remoto (como s3) este test podría llegar a ser extremadamente lento. No lo recomiendo.

Por supuesto que se puede hacer algo de otra manera pero es probable que se ensucie el código en producción (por ejemplo, lo que paso con el parámetro $test del método CustomFile::store) por lo que no lo recomiendo.

Espero te sirva, suerte!